# InfoWindow with Bootstrap layout

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, infowindow

I'm creating an info window and generating its content in javascript, and I want to have a two-column setup inside the window. However, the second div is showing up under the first, not beside (still pulled right though)

Here's a simplified version of what's getting passed to the setContent for the infowindow

```
var contentString ='<div class="info-window"><div class="row"><div class="pull-left span4">'
contentString += "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
contentString += '</div>';
contentString += "<div class='pull-right span1'>";
contentString += "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
contentString += "</div></div></div>";
```

Do infoWindows simply not play nice with the bootstrap scaffolding? Or is there a way to make this work as it should?

Comment: And 5 minutes after I decide I'm stumped enough to ask here, I figure it out. Rubber duck programming!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was coming up because the right column was too tall. Fixing the height of the div and setting the overflow css to auto seems to have mostly fixed things, although I still seem to be somewhat constrained in what I can use for my span widths if I want things to line up properly